# What attack-methods for HTTP/L7-Attacks (Reflection and Co.) are you aware of

Tags: ddos, web, reflection

I know the following and would like to collect some more methods on how to attack websites and services via misused 3rd-party-applications:

- [Wordpress PingBack/xmlrpc](https://isc.sans.edu/forums/diary/Wordpress+Pingback+DDoS+Attacks/17801) (seen a lot and wildly used)
- [Joomla Googlemap-Reflection](http://securityaffairs.co/wordpress/34172/cyber-crime/joomla-reflection-ddos-attacks.html) (seen sometimes)
- [Using Facebook Notes to DDoS any website](http://chr13.com/2014/04/20/using-facebook-notes-to-ddos-any-website/)
- [Using Google to DDoS any website](http://chr13.com/2014/03/10/using-google-to-ddos-any-website/)

i want to collect methods and tools that are designed to attack websites and webservers via http-reflection-attacks.

Comment: Could you be more specific as to what vulnerabilities you are looking for?

Comment: i'm looking for ways, tools and methods to attack websites throught http reflection attacks. these start to get annoying for our clients and i want to know which methoids exists beside those i mentioned